# Yahoo mail keeps asking for my password

Tags: 8.0

I have two Yahoo mail accounts setup on my Mail app on my Lumia 925. My phone is about a month old now, and I have intermittent problems with my Yahoo mail accounts. Once in a while, when I open the Mail app, it prompts me to enter one of my two Yahoo mail account passwords. This has happened more than a dozen times already since I got my phone, and usually prompting just for one of my accounts. I also have two Gmail accounts setup on the same Mail app and I have never been prompted for my passwords for those accounts.

What can I do to prevent this from happening again?

EDIT

A factory reset did not help at all, with one of my Yahoo accounts asking for my password within the same day.

Comment: have you tried resetting the password on the account that's causing the issue then re-entering the password in Settings > Email+Accounts

Comment: @NeilTurner I haven't. I'll try that

Comment: did that work for you?

Comment: Try to delete and re-add the accounts.

Comment: Not that it helps, but I have been having intermittent problems with accessing Yahoo Mail from my HTC 8X (though when that happens it just says "try again later" rather than prompt for password). It seems to be related to the problems/bugs from the overhaul Yahoo did to Mail recently. Personally I am trying to get away from Yahoo Mail now, but that isn't possible for me since I have too many online accounts using that Yahoo address, and the auto-forwarding feature is broken in the new Yahoo Mail.

Comment: I've had the same problem (Lumia 925) for a couple of weeks. Deleting and resetting the account works for a few days then it gets into a cycle of asking for the password every time I open the app *even though* it is successfully downloading new mail.